# Show hidden comments by default

Tags: feature-request, comments

Apologies if this is in the wrong place. By default SE hides some comments on questions or answers when there are several; it seems to hide those with fewest upvotes. But this often leaves dialogue gappy and confusing to read. Since I tend to read down a page, I normally only realise there are hidden comments after having been frustrated by them.

Is there some way to set my preferences to show these comments by default?

Comment: The Stackapp [Threaded comments](http://stackapps.com/q/2050) might do this as a side effect – but I didn’t try it.